# send a join result to view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

i am trying to send a join result to view in which i am getting the exact value in controller but its receiving null value in view. whats wrong with my code.
here is my code

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeGender { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeCity { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeEmail { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ViewModel> vm { get; set; }
    }


public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
            ViewModel vm1 = new ViewModel();
            vm1.vm = from e in employeeContext.Employees
                     join d in employeeContext.Departments on e.DepartmentId equals d.DepartmentId
                     select new ViewModel { EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId, EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName, EmployeeGender = e.EmployeeGender, EmployeeEmail = e.EmployeeEmail, EmployeeCity = e.EmployeeCity, DepartmentName = d.DepartmentName };
            vm1.vm.Single(i => i.EmployeeId == id);
            return View("Details", vm1);
        }
```

View

```
 @model Sample.Models.ViewModel
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
<h4>
      @Model.EmployeeName
</h4>
    @Model.EmployeeCity
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>                                      
     </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you need the send `var result = vm1.vm.Single(i => i.EmployeeId == id);` to the view?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what your wanting to do here. First you set the `vm` property to the results of your query, but nowhere in you code do you ever set the `EmployeeId`, `EmployeeName` etc properties of `ViewModel`. And `vm1.vm.Single(i => i.EmployeeId == id);` does nothing - its just returning one object in the collection but you never assign it to anything. Perhaps you want `var emp = vm1.vm.Single(i => i.EmployeeId == id);` and then `vm.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId;` etc but its a bit unclear

Comment: your suggestion solved my problem. it was just a silly mistake. thanks for your idea..

Answer (score 0):

i think you use wrong method
if you just need the department name from the Departments table you can use the next code

```
EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();

Employe e = employeeContext.Employees.find(id);

ViewModel vm1 = new ViewModel { EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId, EmployeeName = e.EmployeeName, EmployeeGender = e.EmployeeGender, EmployeeEmail = e.EmployeeEmail, EmployeeCity = e.EmployeeCity, DepartmentName = e.Department.name};

return View("Details", vm1);
```